# list all the associated rows ignoring the provided join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of users associated with groups via the group_users table.

I want to list all the users whose associated group name matches the provided search string.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    users.id
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (GROUPs.name)) AS groups_name
FROM
    users
    LEFT OUTER JOIN group_users
        ON groups_users.user_id = users.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GROUPs
        ON GROUPs.id = group_users.group_id
WHERE
    (
        (
            users.type IS NULL
            OR users.type = 'Admin'
        )
        AND ((GROUPs.name LIKE '%light%'))
    )
GROUP BY
    users.id;
```

---

```
+------+-------------------------------+
| id   | groups_name           |
+------+-------------------------------+
|   77 | lightgray olivedrab           |
|  545 | lightseagreen                 |
|  818 | lightseagreen                 |
|  877 | lightseagreen                 |
|  997 | lightgray,lightgray olivedrab |
| 1530 | lightseagreen                 |
| 1532 | lightseagreen                 |
+------+-------------------------------+
```

I want to list all the groups associated with the users matching the LIKE condition in where clause but ignoring it in the group_concat function.

```
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | account_groups_name                                              |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   77 | darkkhaki,lightgray olivedrab                                    |
|  545 | darkolivegreen,darkseagreen,darkslategray,hello,lightseagreen    |
|  818 | darkolivegreen,darkseagreen,darkslategray,hello,lightseagreen    |
|  877 | darkolivegreen,darkseagreen,darkslategray,hello,lightseagreen    |
|  997 | lawngreen,lightgray,lightgray olivedrab,salmon,sandybrown,sienna |
| 1530 | darkolivegreen,darkseagreen,darkslategray,hello,lightseagreen    |
| 1532 | darkolivegreen,darkseagreen,darkslategray,hello,lightseagreen    |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: No need for SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Move the groups.name condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I got all your requirements right, your query can be simplified by using `group_concat` in the having clause.

```
SELECT users.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (GROUPs.name)) AS groups_name
FROM
    users
    JOIN group_users
        ON group_users.user_id = users.id
    JOIN GROUPs
        ON GROUPs.id = group_users.group_id
WHERE (users.type IS NULL OR users.type = 'Admin')
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (GROUPs.name)) LIKE '%light%';
```

Refer SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8c136/4/0